# Basic Integration Question, Possibly By Substitution

Tags: integration

How to integrate the function $f(x)= \dfrac{x}{(1+x^2)^{1/2}}$.

I think it can be done by substitution, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3):

$$Let, \space 1+x^2 = t $$

$$2xdx = dt$$

$$ \int f(x) dx = \int \frac{x}{\mathrm{(1+x^2)}^{1/2}}dx $$

$$ I  =  \int \frac{1}{2\mathrm{t}^{1/2}}dt$$

$$ I = \frac{1}{2}\int \mathrm{t}^{-1/2}dt = \frac{1}{2}\times \frac{\mathrm{t}^{1/2}}{\frac{1}{2}} + C $$

$$ I = \mathrm{t}^{1/2} + C $$

Now Substitute the value of $t$ in term of $x$

$$ I = \mathrm{(1+x^2)}^{1/2} + C$$

$$ \int f(x) dx  = \sqrt{1+x^2}\space + C$$

Answer (score 1):

Directly:

$$\int \frac x{\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx=\frac12\int\frac{(x^2)'\,dx}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}=\sqrt{1+x^2}+C$$

Based on the general case

$$\int\frac{f'(x)}{\sqrt{1+f(x)}}dx=2\sqrt{1+f(x)}+C$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Put $x=a\tan\theta$ for $a^2+x^2$ in the radical

Put $x=a\sin\theta$ for $a^2-x^2$ in the radical

Put $x=a\sec\theta$ for $x^2-a^2$ in the radical

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution